# How to make a draggable handler that can change a div's css

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag, onmousedown

I'm making a handler function
here is the demo:
http://codepen.io/iamkaikai/pen/myVzvY?editors=011

Here's my question,
The blue div's width is 0, and I use jQuery to give it a width by reading pageX when on click
However, I would like the blue div's width follows the changing of pageX instead of change only once.
My goal is to make a draggable handler that can switch red div to blue div

Here is the code:

```
$( "#line" ).draggable({
   containment: "#red";
});

$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {

   $( "#line" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX );
   $("#line").mousedown(function(){
      $("#blue").css("width", event.pageX);
   });

});
```

I know javascript only read the first pageX once when you click the div, 
how do I make it read all the mouse position in one mouse down event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Document denotes the whole document width :
2. (#)line denotes the width of the #line div :

   ```
    $( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
     $( "#line" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX );
   });

   $("#line").on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
     $("#blue").css("width", event.pageX);
   });
   ```

Comment: thanks man! 
Another question, why is there a little delay when dragging?

Answer (score 0):

Property `pageX` will return the result on your event, as the event `mousedown` is triggering for one time only.

Event `mousemove` will capture mouse movement on your div and trigger the event with its movement.

Check this out:

```
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $( "#line" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX );
});

$("#line").on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $("#blue").css("width", event.pageX);
});
```